# what does "key in in" mean?

Tags: meaning

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/eIZpQpx0b0M?t=28) (a video link with a time stamp)

> I know
>   a lot of you guys also do not own your
>   own home. so I thought I would actually
>   **key in in** on what I did to solve my problem

a similar phrase is "[key sth in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/key-sth-in?q=key%20in)", which means

> to put information into a computer, phone, or other machine using a keyboard or touchscreen

which does not apply that expression very well. So, what does "key in in" mean?

Comment: It sounds like a self-invented version of 'chime in' or other similar expressions, meaning 'contribute' [my own experience].

Comment: I agree that it's somewhat self-invented, but I think his meaning is more similar to "hone in" as in "identify specifically".

Comment: 'Hone in', (alteration of 'home in') is widely considered to be an error outside the US and Canada.